# What does "when I was still but a child" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "was still but" mean in this sentence?

> This game brings back memories. Used to watch my dad play it when I **was still but a child**. Only last week we found out that you can in
> fact play this game in co-op. Guess who's having great bonding time
> with her dad now?

source: https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198126630264/recommended/704450/

Comment: Have you looked up 'but' in a good dictionary such as Cambridge Dictionary?

Comment: And can you please cite your source?

Comment: I have aded the source

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as answerable by a dictionary. "still but a child" is an unusual construction and I can see how it would be confusing to a learner.

Answer (score 3):

The cited text probably didn't come from a native Anglophone. This use of ***but*** to mean ***just, only, merely*** is formal / dated / literary. Which is totally incompatible with the informal conversational tone of the rest of the text. A native speaker would say...

> ***I** used to watch my dad play [**it**] when I was **just a kid***

(In practice I don't think many people would include ***it*** there, but most of us *wouldn't* omit the initial first person singular pronoun in this exact context.)

Comment: A modern day Anglophone yes, it does sound a bit old fashioned. For example the Hymn "Suppertime" by Ira F. Stanphill 1914-1993 https://www.elyrics.net/read/c/cathedrals-lyrics/suppertime-lyrics.html  starts "*When I was but a boy in days of childhood*" . If you google the phrase "*when I was but*" there are a few hits, but it appears that they are used for artistic purposes, mostly in poetry even to this day. But I confess I can't find the exact phrase with the extra "I" and "still" in it.

Comment: There will always be a few "linguistic dinosaurs" - but seriously, who cares what a hymn-writer born before WW1 put in his lyrics? And in any case, few if any hymns have lyrics appropriate to the relaxed informal conversational tone of OP's cited text. And *that* "incompatibility" is at least as significant as the difference between today's norms in English, and what they wrote many decades or even centuries ago.

Comment: I, an atheist,  care a bit what hymn writers born before 1914 such as Toplady and "Saint" John Newman put in their lyrics, and if I am a dinosaur because I like, _inter alios_, Dickens, Smollett, Shakespeare, and Chaucer, then so be it.

Comment: Also Twain and Hemingway.

Comment: Well, yes. But we're not teaching *literature* here (my degree, as it happens). We're just helping non-native Anglophones learn the basics of (essentially, *current*, primarily *spoken*) English. More advanced literature-oriented Anglophiles probably wouldn't be here anyway.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have added source in my question. It is a comment for video game " Neverwinter Nights: Enhanced Edition"(a DND game). In my opnion, it is as @Peter Jennings said, he used **but** here to make it "sound a bit old fashioned".

Comment: @AdmiralOrange: ***If*** it's from a native speaker (which I still doubt), it's the written equivalent of a "telephone voice" (someone trying to speak in a "register" they're not familiar with, so their utterances seem unnatural). It wouldn't make sense to include just *one* such "literary device" in a context where it's clearly incompatible with the modern colloquial tone of the rest of the text. Imho it's a writer who doesn't *usually* write such text, which leads to quirky inconsistencies.

Comment: There is a good chance that the writer is from Belgium. (On his steam profile, he is a member of BELGIUM group.) English is Belgium‘s first foreign language.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - if _literature_ was, as it happens, your degree subject, I'd better be very careful what I say, I think.

Comment: People who are interested in literature (learners or native Anglophones) can pursue such matters on writers.se. All I'm doing here is noting that the particular utterance OP has unearthed (probably *not* from a native speaker) is neither idiomatic nor common, and should *not* be committed to memory or replicated by the kind of users we expect here. I'm not "anti-literature", but this isn't the place to make an issue of that.